# Navigation won't display in wordpress theme tesseract

Tags: wordpress

so I am working with the tesseract theme 2015, and I adjusted the navigation or the main nav menu.  I delete the nav name or done something wrong, but right now the nav menu won't display.  when I shrink the screen on my laptop down to mobile size I see the mobile menu icon.  When I click it I see 'undefined' in place of the Nav menu.  Oh by the I'm working in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have forgot to set some "Theme location" on your menu?

Comment: I am new to wordpress where can find "Theme location"

Comment: 1. Go to "yourwebsiteurl.com/wp-admin"
2. Appearence > Menu